# What is the safest hard drive format for archiving media storage data?

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, windows, hard-disk

What is the safest hard drive format (NTFS, HFS+, XFS, ZFS, ...) for archiving or/and storing media (data)? I'd prefer to have the data not corrupt and be relatively safe from corruption and other things. I would also like to have the format to be accessible by Windows (Vista) as well.

Answer (score 4):

Stick with ext3 or ext4. While other formats such as ZFS certainly have their advantages, few filesystems (other than NTFS) have as broad OS support as ext3/4.

Comment: NTFS does not have broad, quality support.

Answer (score 2):

Your main limit is Windows access. If it wasn't for that, you'd probably be best off with ZFS... *If* you used *BSD instead of Linux. But as you have Ubuntu, I'd say: **stick with ext4**.

This will not be natively supported by Windows, but nothing really good will - and the `ext` family is most popular and stable, so many 3rd party Windows programs offer support for it (like Total Commander plugins). Since Ext4 can be mounted in backward-compatibility mode, you'd probably be able to use some programs that by default support only ext2/3.

Answer (score 1):

`tar` is a rock-solid, append-only filesystem, which is well-suited to archiving.  You can write raw to tar from UNIX, so:

```
tar cf -b $BLOCKSIZE /dev/hda ~
```

or from Windows you can create/extract tar files using the very capable Winzip, but that leaves you with the problem of raw read/write dev access from Windows.  Since Windows Server 2003, this has been tricky to do, but [the code from the DiskSector project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/rawsectorio.aspx) (untested!) looks promising.  I leave this as a project for yourself to package this up into convenient scripts...